# SDL Get Keyboard State without using Events

Tags: c++, events, keyboard, gtk, sdl

Does anyone know how to get SDL_GetKeyState to work properly, without having to setup a loop which polls the SDL Events?

```
int *keystates;
keystates = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
SDL_PumpEvents();
std::cout << "Test 1\n";
if (keystates[SDLK_F1]) {
    std::cout << "Test 1 Okay\n";
    key_ac = true;
    emu->setPower(true);
}
```

This code is run over 100 times a second, however even when I hold down the F1 key, I still do not get any output to say it was successful.

I have no SDL event loop, so could this be that events are being discarded because I'm not using them? In which case, how could I get SDL to filter out all events?

Comment: What is your specific question/problem? How to make thing A work is too broad.

Comment: How to get SDL_GetKeyState to work properly, without having to setup a loop which polls the SDL Events? Sorry I should have made it a bit clearer

Comment: By using it as specified in the documents, and not using an event loop.

Comment: The documents state "Note: Use SDL_PumpEvents to update the state array." However this is not working in my case.

Comment: Well then make it work, that is as much as I can help with the information you provided.

Comment: Thats the part im stuck on. Making it work :/
Ive added some code example. Anything else that might make it clearer?

Comment: You should not have both SDL and GTK+ handling input events. SDL can only do very basic input handling anyways, I would just use a GTK+ callback and maintain my own keystates[] array.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the option I'm going to go with. It seems the simplest to implement and means I can keep all my event handling to only one toolkit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SDL_GetKeyState()` only has to be called once at the start of your program.

```
unsigned char * keys = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL);
```

Then the value it returns, a unsigned char pointer to an array is stored internally. To to update the state of the array call the function `SDL_PumpEvents()`.

To update array `keys` in your main loop:

```
SDL_PumpEvents();

if( keys[ SDLK_m ] )
{
    //do stuff
}
```

EDIT:
You can call `SDL_GetKeyState()` as much as you want after the first call and you won't create a memory leak. The function is always returning the same pointer.

Comment: This works fine for me on its own. I just found out my problem is due to me using GTK and SDL together, it seems SDL doesn't handle events properly when used with GTK. Ill mark this solution as correct though, as in a normal situation this is the correct answer.

For me, I think im going to have to look into a way of getting gtk to handle the keyboard inputs or pass them to sdl. But thats a whole different question.